# Plotting random, non overlapping divs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container of approximately 600 by 400 pixels, into which I want to randomly place between 2 and 10 random sized rectangles.

Placing them is easy enough, but they must not overlap - which is where I am having the problem. Is there an algorithm I can use to make sure that the rectangles never touch or overlap?

I'm using jQuery and absolute positioned divs, no canvas or HTML5 of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep an array of positions as you're generating them. If the next position is in the array, re-randomize.

Comment: Hi James - sounds interesting, could you explain a little more? I'm not 100% sure how to do that

Comment: Say you're generating your X and Y co-ordinates in a loop. Every time the loop has executed, store the X and Y in an array. At the beginning of the loop, you do a check to see if the X and Y is already in the array, if it is, generate the numbers again :)

Comment: James - that would mean only a match if the X and Y were exactly the same wouldn't it? Meaning overlap can still occur. Unless you mean using a 2 dimensional array of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a [bounding box collision detection](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/game-programming/collision-detection/collision-detection-r735). You need to keep an array of all your boxes and their sizes.